# Very slow distinct and sort method in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following view: http://pastebin.com/jgLeM3cd and the size of my database is about 10 GB. The problem is because of `DISTINCT` the view execution is really, really slow.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    users.id AS user_id, 
    contacts.id AS contact_id,
    contact_types.name AS relationship, 
    channels.name AS channel,
    feed_items.send_at AS sent_at, 
    feed_items.body AS message,
    feed_items.from_id, 
    feed_items.feed_id
FROM feed_items
JOIN channels ON feed_items.channel_id = channels.id
JOIN feeds ON feed_items.feed_id = feeds.id
JOIN contacts ON feeds.contact_id = contacts.id
JOIN contact_types ON contacts.contact_type_id = contact_types.id
JOIN users ON contacts.user_id = users.id
WHERE contacts.is_fake = false;
```

For example, here is the analyze of the execution with `LIMIT 10`: https://explain.depesz.com/s/K8q2

```
   QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=7717200.06..7717200.28 rows=10 width=1113) (actual time=118656.704..118656.726 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=7717200.06..7780174.02 rows=2798843 width=1113) (actual time=118656.702..118656.723 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=7717200.06..7724197.16 rows=2798843 width=1113) (actual time=118656.700..118656.712 rows=10 loops=1)
               Sort Key: users.id, contacts.id, contact_types.name, channels.name, feed_items.send_at, feed_items.body, feed_items.from_id, feed_items.feed_id
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 589888kB
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=22677.02..577531.86 rows=2798843 width=1113) (actual time=416.072..12918.259 rows=5301453 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (feed_items.channel_id = channels.id)
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=22675.84..539046.59 rows=2798843 width=601) (actual time=416.052..10703.796 rows=5301636 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (contacts.contact_type_id = contact_types.id)
                           ->  Hash Join  (cost=22674.73..500479.61 rows=2820650 width=89) (actual time=416.038..8494.439 rows=5303074 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (feed_items.feed_id = feeds.id)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on feed_items  (cost=0.00..223787.54 rows=6828254 width=77) (actual time=0.025..2300.762 rows=6820169 loops=1)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=18314.88..18314.88 rows=250788 width=16) (actual time=415.830..415.830 rows=268669 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 4096  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 806kB
                                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=1642.22..18314.88 rows=250788 width=16) (actual time=19.562..337.146 rows=268669 loops=1)
                                             Hash Cond: (feeds.contact_id = contacts.id)
                                             ->  Seq Scan on feeds  (cost=0.00..11888.11 rows=607111 width=8) (actual time=0.013..116.339 rows=607117 loops=1)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=1517.99..1517.99 rows=9938 width=12) (actual time=19.537..19.537 rows=9945 loops=1)
                                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 427kB
                                                   ->  Hash Join  (cost=619.65..1517.99 rows=9938 width=12) (actual time=5.743..16.746 rows=9945 loops=1)
                                                         Hash Cond: (contacts.user_id = users.id)
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on contacts  (cost=0.00..699.58 rows=9938 width=12) (actual time=0.005..5.981 rows=9945 loops=1)
                                                               Filter: (NOT is_fake)
                                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 14120
                                                         ->  Hash  (cost=473.18..473.18 rows=11718 width=4) (actual time=5.728..5.728 rows=11800 loops=1)
                                                               Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 415kB
                                                               ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..473.18 rows=11718 width=4) (actual time=0.004..2.915 rows=11800 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=1.05..1.05 rows=5 width=520) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=5 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on contact_types  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=520) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=5 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=1.08..1.08 rows=8 width=520) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=8 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on channels  (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=8 width=520) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=8 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 118765.513 ms
(34 rows)
```

I've created b-tree indexes on almost all columns that are used except `feed_items.body` because this is `text` column. I also increased `work_mem` but it didn't help. Any ideas how can I speed it up?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but slow still is a relative term, doesnt say how much time take, or show the `CREATE TABLE` with index information.

Comment: Do you really need the distinct on **all** columns? The biggest problem is that there isn't enough work_mem available to complete the sort in memory ("Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 589888kB") One way to tackle this is to increase `work_mem`, e.g. `set session work_mem='1GB';` (if you have enough memory)

Comment: If you just need distinct users, then `distinct on (user_id)` might be faster (because the sort/distinct is only done on a single integer column)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not sure how that `work_mem`, but for `589888kB` wont you need 600gb RAM?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: the memory required for an in-memory sort is usually much bigger then the one required for an on-disk sort

Comment: That's also my first thought: it seems you need distinct `feed_items`, so you should try with `distinct on (feed_item_id)` (if that's a thing) -- also, you join tables what you never use, f.ex. `users` (in the select part, you can write `contacts.user_id` directly).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, but you say need `1gb`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: 589888kB are 576 **MB** if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You may be right. Now regarding the OP. Doesnt all those `SEQ SCAN` hint the `index` arent OK ?

Comment: My suggestion is try to `JOIN` one table to each time and check the `EXPLAIN ANALIZE` to see if you are using the index. Also see what `JOIN` is the one making thing slow.

Comment: Exactly that. My guess is that a few joinfields are missing (somewhere in the contact_type,feeds -area) and that the `DISTINCT` does a lot of work to suppress the resulting duplicates. What is also missing is table definitions.

Comment: All I need is to avoid duplicated feed_items so could I use `distinct` on `body` column? If not what column should it be used on? 

@pozs I join `users` table because I need to get a user ID which is selected as first column.

Comment: `I've created b-tree indexes on almost all columns that are used except ...` That is not a data model, it is a spreadsheet with indexes. Without table definitions (including keys, indexes, and approximate sizes, your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

As others said in comments:

- Use *DISTINCT* with as few as possible fields.

  - Maybe you only need a *GROUP BY*...
- Increasing *work_mem* could help, but it is not a definitive solution (you have a very inefficient query and, as database will grow, it will degrade again...)

Also:

- Index could hardly help in large scan queries like this: Indexes can pick concrete results faster, but full scan on index is highly more expensive than a sequential scan over a table (or join).
- The only exception to that is when you only need to pick a few records of a big table. But the planner will hardly guess it so you will need to force it by using a subquery or a CTE ("WITH" clause).
- In the same line of *work_mem* increasing, 9.6 version of PostgreSQL comes with parallel scan capabilities (it must be enabled by hand first): If your server is that version or you have chance to upgrade it, it also could accelerate the response time (even, anyway, your query seems to need to be improved... ;-)).

So, my recommendation is to try to reduce as much as possible the data involved in the join. And specially in the first joins. That is: **the joining order does matter**. Remember that (fortunately) you haven't any left joins, so each join is actually a potential filter, so picking first for shorter tables (or tables in which you will pick fewer rows) can considerably reduce memory needed for the join.

For example, (based on your query, not tested at all and REMEMBER, your data distribution matters):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    users.id AS user_id,
    contacts.id AS contact_id,
    contact_types.name AS relationship,
    channels.name AS channel,
    feed_items.send_at AS sent_at,
    feed_items.body AS message,
    feed_items.from_id,
    feed_items.feed_id
-- Base your query in contacts because is the only place where you are making
-- some discardings:
FROM contacts
JOIN feeds ON (
    contacts.is_fake = false -- Filter here to reduce join size
    and feeds.contact_id = contacts.id -- Actual join condition
)
JOIN feed_items ON feed_items.feed_id = feeds.id
JOIN channels ON channels.id = feed_items.channel_id
JOIN contact_types ON contacts.contact_type_id = contact_types.id
JOIN users ON contacts.user_id = users.id
;
```

But, again: All depends on your actual data.

Try it, *EXPLAIN ANALYZE* it, identify the most expensive parts, and think about strategies to improve it.

That was only a few random ideas, but I hope it could help you a bit.

Good luck!

Comment: The derived table (that needs an alias btw) won't change anything, and neither does the order of the tables in the FROM clause.